# interpret effect of interaction term between two binary variables on continuous outcome

Tags: regression, interaction

If I set up an interaction term between two dichotomous variables, let's say experiment (1= control, 2 = experiment group)  and gender (1 = male , 2 = female). If the effect of the interaction term (experiment*gender) on happiness is .46 using regression, does that mean the experiment increased happiness in females more than males?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues of statistical significance aside, that would be the interpretation as long as you had the level effects as well (say if your model also included a constant as well as experiment and gender coefficients).